# Ordering event by date

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame of app installs which has one row per user per install - so that a user who has installed multiple apps will have multiple rows.

The columns are user name, app name, and install date.  A user can install multiple apps on the same day.

How can I find the order of occurrence of app installs, with apps that were installed on the same day being ranked as the same install order?

What I would like is to pass in the User, App, and Date and then get the order

`User  App  Date       Order
0   A   1   4/23/2019  3
1   A   2   4/23/2019  3
2   A   3   4/20/2019  2
3   A   4   3/15/2019  1
4   B   1   3/1/2019   1
5   B   2   3/1/2019   1
6   B   3   3/1/2019   1
7   C   1   3/1/2019   1
8   C   2   5/1/2019   2
9   C   3   8/1/2019   3`

Comment: Can you include a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: @rahlf23 - I have added an example of what I am trying to achieve. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `rank`

```
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.groupby('User').Date.rank(method='min',ascending=True)
0    3.0
1    3.0
2    2.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    1.0
8    2.0
9    3.0
Name: Date, dtype: float64
df['Order']= df.groupby('User').Date.rank(method='min',ascending=True).astype(int)
```

Comment: Cheers @Wen-Ben, this got me to where I needed to get. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a sample dataframe

```
User    App Date
0   A   1   4/23/2019
1   A   2   4/23/2019
2   B   3   4/20/2019
3   B   4   3/15/2019
4   B   5   3/1/2019
5   C   6   3/1/2019
6   C   7   3/1/2019
```

From what it sounds, if you're trying to group apps that were installed on the same day, you can do this with a groupby

```
df_grouped=df.groupby(['Date'])['App'].unique().reset_index()
```

resulting in

```
Date    App
0   3/1/2019    [5 6 7]
1   3/15/2019   [4]
2   4/20/2019   [3]
3   4/23/2019   [1 2]
```

Comment: Hey @Nev1111 - thank you so much for the response, really appreciate you taking the time. That's almost kind of what I am looking for, I edited the question with the output that I'm looking for. Hopefully this is more illustrative. Cheers